# How to use Callable with void return type?

Tags: java, multithreading, callable

I am working on a project in which I have multiple interface and two Implementations classes which needs to implement these two interfaces.

Suppose my first Interface is -

```
public Interface interfaceA {
    public void abc() throws Exception;
}
```

And its implementation is -

```
public class TestA implements interfaceA {

// abc method
}
```

I am calling it like this -

```
TestA testA = new TestA();
testA.abc();
```

Now my second interface is -

```
public Interface interfaceB {
    public void xyz() throws Exception;
}
```

And its implementation is -

```
public class TestB implements interfaceB {

// xyz method   
}
```

I am calling it like this -

```
TestB testB = new TestB();
testB.xyz();
```

**Problem Statement:-**

Now my question is - Is there any way, I can execute these two implementation classes in parallel? I don't want to run it in sequential.

Meaning, I want to run `TestA` and `TestB` implementation in parallel? Is this possible to do?

I was thinking to use Callable here but not sure how to use Callable with void return type here -

Let's use TestB class as an example:

```
public interface interfaceB {
    public void xyz() throws Exception;
}

public class TestB implements interfaceB, Callable<?>{

    @Override
    public void xyz() throws Exception
    {
        //do something

    }

    @Override
    public void call() throws Exception
    {
        xyz();
    }
}
```

Above code gives compilation error..

**UPDATE:-**

It looks like lot of people are suggesting to use Runnable instead of callable. But not sure how do I use Runnable here so that I can execute `TestA and TestB` in parallel.

Comment: You can use `Void` instead if `void` and return `null` as dummy return value.

Comment: You may want to use `Runnable` instead of `Callable`.

Comment: @ajb: Can you provide an example if possible how to use Runnable here so that I can execute TestA and TestB in parallel.

Comment: @ajb `Runnable` may not work in some scenarios. For one: [`ExecutorService#invokeAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#invokeAll(java.util.Collection)) takes a collection of `Callable` but does *not* take a collection of `Runnable`.

Answer (score 98, accepted):

You can use *java.lang.Thread* for parallel execution. However, in most cases it's easier to use an *java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService*. The latter provides a method to submit a *Callable* and returns a *Future* to get the result later (or wait for completion).

If *testA.abc()* and *testB.xyz()* should be executed in parallel, you use the *ExecutorService* to execute the former in a separate thread whereas the latter is executed in the original thread. Then you wait for the completion of the former for synchronization.

```
ExecutorService executor = ... // e.g. Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);

Future<Void> future = executor.submit(new Callable<Void>() {
    public Void call() throws Exception {
        testA.abc();
        return null;
    }
});
testB.xyz();
future.get(); // wait for completion of testA.abc()
```

Comment: Very Nice! I did not know we have a Void class to be used there in the template parameter...

Answer (score 4):

Why would you need a void for running something in Parallel? For one, if you don't need the return value, you can simply return `null`.

To make something parallel you need to use threading/scheduling. I would personally recommend avoiding Callables, and using Runnables instead (and hey, no return value).

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. Then can you provide me an example how I can execute TestA and TestB in parallel using Runnable instead of callable?

Comment: ExecutorService is probably the best approach to execute two tasks in parallel. It also supports _Runnable_. However, _Callable_ has the advantage to also support arbitrary exceptions.

Comment: Rogue- what's the problem with using callables in this situation?

Comment: @IcedDante I've always avoided them because of their exception handling, which lead to me having to debug stuff just to find out the exception in a callable is being raised and not printed / thrown out of the context

Comment: How does one use `Runnable` with [`ExecutorService#invokeAll​( Collection<? extends Callable<T>> tasks )`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#invokeAll(java.util.Collection))?

Comment: @BasilBourque if you had a list of runnables, then `list.forEach(executor::submit)`; the alternative of wrapping all of those runnables into `Callable` objects defeats the purpose in terms of the exception handling comments above. That said, `Callable` doesn't need to be avoided completely, if you have a list of objects that you want to render into `Future`s accordingly with return values, `Callable` is appropriate. Just be aware of the exception handling.

Answer (score 3):

A shorter version:

```
ExecutorService executor = ... // e.g. Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);
Future<?> future = executor.submit(() -> testA.abc());
testB.xyz();
future.get(); // wait for completion of testA.abc()
```

To be noted that having to run something in parallel with nothing to be returned could be a sign of a bad pattern :)

Also, if you are in a Spring environment, you could use: https://spring.io/guides/gs/async-method/